# gfortran gives undefined reference to `dacosd_` even with `-dec-math`

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gnu, gfortran, compiler-flags

I'm trying to compile a Fortran application using `gfortran`, linking with Intel MKL libraries.

> undefined reference to `dacosd_'

There is a `acos` or `acosd` (inverse cosine in degree), I'm almost there but I can't compile using `-fall-intrinsics` or `-dec-math` flag, as instructed in the manual, because it all yields the same error.

Where have I got it wrong, and how can I compile this?

The `gfortran` version I'm using is 5.4.1.

Comment: I don't think acosd and friends are  available for that old version of the compiler. Check the documentation for that particular release. I'd steer well clear of it anyway as it isn't standard. Just define a parameter equal to `180.0/pi` in whatever precision you like and multiply.

Comment: Are you still using the `-std=2008`? It is important to say the **complete** command! I will look for an answer later, if nobody else finds it earlier, but notice what the manual says: *"This function is for compatibility only and should be avoided in favor of standard constructs wherever possible."* You can just use `acos()` and convert the argument as RussF says. He may also be right that you need a newer version.

Comment: BTW, I believe it is `-fdec-math`, not `-dec-math`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RussF commented, these non-standard extension functions are included in gfortran 7 and later. You need a newer version. Also, the correct flag is `-fdec-math`, not `-dec-math`.

```
intrinsic dacosd

print *, dacosd(0.5d0)
end
```

compile as:

```
> gfortran-6 -fdec-math dacosd.f90 
gfortran-6: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fdec-math’; did you mean ‘-ffast-math’?
> gfortran-7 -fdec-math dacosd.f90
> ./a.out 
   60.000000000000007
```

You can easily do the same computation with a conversion

```
double precision, parameter :: pi = acos(-1.d0)
print *, acos(0.5d0)*180/pi
end
```

or you can define your own `(d)acosd` function this way, to stay portable.

Comment: omg it really worked! i install `gfortran-7` on ubuntu (for some reasons the default `gfortran` version stays as low as 5.4.0 so you have to manually update/upgrade it). get an `intrinsic` in there really helps me solve the problem! thanks a lot and happy holiday!